# HTML form with checkbox options to select fieldset

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form that is like the following:

```
<label>
  scale a<input type="radio" name="sellorbuy" value="Yes" id="rdYes" />
</label>
<label class="leftspace">
  scale b<input type="radio" name="sellorbuy" value="No" id="rdNo" />
</label>

<p class="searchpg">Price</p>

<fieldset id="sell">
  <select id="pricemin" name="minsell" class="form-control">
    <option value="50000">Min Price</option>
    <option value="100000">£100,000</option>
    <option value="200000" >£200,000</option>
    <option value="300000" >£300,000</option>
    <option value="400000" >£400,000</option>             
  </select>

  <select id="pricemax" name="maxsell" class="form-control">
    <option value="5000000">Max Price</option>
    <option value="100000">£100,000</option>
    <option value="200000">£200,000</option>
    <option value="300000">£300,000</option>
    <option value="400000">£400,000</option>
    <option value="500000">£500,000</option>             
  </select>
</fieldset>

<fieldset id="let" style="display:none;">
  <select id="lpricemin" name="minbuy" class="form-control">
    <option value="500">Min Price</option>
    <option value="500">£500</option>
    <option value="600">£600</option>
    <option value="700">£700</option>
    <option value="800">£800</option>
    <option value="900">£900</option>
  </select>

  <select id="lpricemax" name="maxbuy" class="form-control">
    <option value="5000">Max Price</option>
    <option value="600">£600</option>
    <option value="700">£700</option>
    <option value="800">£800</option>
    <option value="900">£900</option>
    <option value="1000">£1000</option>
    <option value="1150">£1150</option>
  </select>
</fieldset>
```

This switches fieldsets by using the following:

```
$("input[name='sellorlet']").change(function () {
    $("#sell").toggle(this.value == "Yes");
    $("#let").toggle(this.value == "No");
});
```

The trouble I am having is the search form that is submitted and displayed on the next page so we carry over the contents of the form. If someone has selected the 'Scale B' then that is already toggled on the next page but the fieldset has not changed? Is there any way to change to the jquery to detect which checkbox is toggled and change the fieldset accordingly or even modify the switch to make it work better?

Created a fiddle to show how the form works https://jsfiddle.net/v3waaa20/1/

Comment: How are you passing the contents of the form to the next page? Do you simply need to pass the currently selected values from the drop-downs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some slight changes and triggering change on load can do the trick.

```
$("input[name='sellorbuy']").change(function () {
    value = $("input[name='sellorbuy']:checked").val();
    $("#sell").toggle(value == "Yes");
    $("#let").toggle(value == "No");
}).change();
```

Comment: Doesn't declaring `value` without the keyword `var` assign the variable to the global scope?